# In Tensorflow JS, using Node (tfjs-node) is there any way to Load Universal Sentence Encoder (USE) from local File?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a tensorflow.js script/app that runs in Node.js using tfjs-node and Universal Sentence Encoder (USE).

Each Time the script runs, it downloads a 525 MegaByte File (the USE model file).

Is there any way to load the Universal Sentence Encoder Model File from the local file system to avoid downloading such a large file every time I need to run the node.js tensorflow script?

I've noted several similar model loading examples but none that work with Universal Sentence Encoder as it does not appear to have the same type functionality. Below is a stripped down example of a functioning script that downloads the 525 MB file every time it executes.

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const use = require('@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder');

// No Form of Universal Sentence Encoder loader appears to be present

let model = tf.loadGraphModel('file:///Users/ray/Documents/tf_js_model_save_load2/models/model.json');

use.load().then(model => {

    const sentences = [
      'Hello.',
      'How are you?'
    ];

    model.embed(sentences).then(embeddings => {
      embeddings.print(true /* verbose */);
    });
  });
```

I've tried several recommendations that appear to work for other models but not Universal Sentence Encoder such as:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

async function loadModel(){
    const handler = tfnode.io.fileSystem('tfjs_model/model.json');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    console.log("Model loaded")
}


loadModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

its not a *model* issue per-say, its a *module* issue.
model can be loaded any way you want, but the *module* `@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder` implements only a specific internal way on how it loads actual model data.

specifically, it internally uses `tf.util.fetch`.

solution? use some library (or write your own) to register a global `fetch` handler that knows how to handle `file://` prefixes - if global `fetch` handler exists, `tf.util.fetch` will simply just use it.

hint: https://gist.github.com/joshua-gould/58e1b114a67127273eef239ec0af8989

Comment: Thank you, Sincerely appreciate the insights - I will give your recommendation a try!